# execute a function when the success data arrived in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know that's some kind of callback concept, but have no idea how to do that.

```
$.ajax({
       'url': '/test/',
       'type': 'POST',
       'data': {'age': age},
       'dataType': 'html',
       'success': function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

         //I want when the data arrives, then execute another function, because the function is too big to place here.

        }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to execute *only* some other function with takes the data as a parameter, do this:

```
$.ajax({
   'url': '/test/',
   'type': 'POST',
   'data': {'age': age},
   'dataType': 'html',
   'success': myFunction
});

//then, defined anywhere that's in scope:
function myFunction(data) {
  //do something with data
}
```

---

If you need to do some work *then* call that function...do just that:

```
$.ajax({
   'url': '/test/',
   'type': 'POST',
   'data': {'age': age},
   'dataType': 'html',
   'success': function(data) {
     //do stuff...
     myFunction(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: so what's the signature of myFunction?

Comment: @user469652 - just like I have it above, the same signature as the [docs have for the `success` callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): `func(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)`, if you don't need the other parameters, just have one for `data` like I have above.